# Method to check if both stacks are equal

Tags: java, stack

Given the following class definition for `ArrayStack`:

```
Public class ArrayStack<T> implements Stack {

    T[] stack;
    int topIndex = -1;
```

Write a method equals(Stack other) in class ArrayStack that takes a Stack as parameter and returns true if both stacks are equal, and false otherwise.

```
    public boolean equals(Stack<T> other) {
```

Code for ArrayStack.java

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.EmptyStackException;

    public class ArrayStack<T> implements Stacks<T> {

      T[] stack;
      int topIndex = -1;
      private final static int DEFCAP = 100;

      public ArrayStack(int maxSize) {
        stack = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
      }

      public ArrayStack() {
        this(DEFCAP);
      }

      @Override
      public void push(T element) {
        if (topIndex == stack.length - 1) {
          enlarge();
        }
        topIndex++;
        stack[topIndex] = element;
      }

      @Override
      public T pop() {
        return stack[topIndex--];
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isEmpty() {
        return topIndex == -1;
      }

      @Override
      public  T peak() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
          return stack[topIndex];
        } else {
          throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
      }

      private void enlarge() {
        stack = Arrays.copyOf(stack, stack.length + DEFCAP);
      }
    }
```

My attempt: Im seriously pissed at how bad my attempt was but i'm just too closed at the moment and i can't think properly. Need your help please in thinking this question!

```
public boolean equals(Stack<T> other) {
    if(! other.isEmpty() ) {
        for(int i=0; i < stack.length; i++) {
            if(stack[i].equals(Other.stack[i]) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Reverse your logic. You're returning `true` on the first element.

Comment: For starters you probably don't want to return true if the first element in the stack's are equal.

Comment: @Bhesh you codified some stuff that didn't need to be.

Comment: Also, you can quickly test the following three cases at the beginning:  this is empty and other is empty, this is empty and other isn't, this isn't empty and other is

Comment: You'll need to handle the .equals(null) case.  Also, and this is just me being a jerk probably: it's `peek()`, not `peak()`.

Comment: @Brandon is right. You should also test unequal lengths. In fact, you MUST do so, since your loop will blow up if other's stack is shorter than stack. Oh, and "Other" should be lower case. Actually, checking for unequal lengths tests all three of Brandon's conditions; see Kevin's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Stack<T> other) {
    //If they point to the same object return true
    if (stack == other) return true;
    //Check for nulls
    if (stack == null || other == null) return false;
    //If the stacks are not the same length, then they won't be equal, easy first test case
    if (stack.length != other.size()) return false;

    for(int i=0; i < stack.length; i++) {
           //Step through each item in both stacks, if any don't match return false
           if(!stack[i].equals(other.stack[i]) ) {
                  return false;
           }
    }

    //Haven't returned yet, they must be equal
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also, consider making this null-argument safe and null-element safe.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia `if (stack == null && other == null) return true;`

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia error when !stack[i].equals(Other.stack[i] : non static variable used from a static content or something.

Comment: Just start the method with if (stack == other) return true;  If they point to the same object then they're equal, and that also handles the situation where they're both null etc...

Comment: Marko may have a point. Add the @Override tag and see if it throws a wobbly. I think it will. Traditionally, equals() takes an *Object* argument and the first thing you do is test to see if the argument is an instance of your base class. Then cast to your base class and continue.

Comment: @Kyle are you instantiating an instance of your stack class?

Comment: If **both** stacks are `null` it should return `true` IMO

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia this code as asked is created inside the ArrayStack class.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia the errors are if(!stack[i].equals(other.stack[i] : cannot find symbol variable stack in the other.stack[i]

Comment: if (stack.length != other.length) length too gives an error cannot find symbol.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia fixed the static errors now the errors are all cannot find symbol for other when it checks for equals lengths and in the for loop checking if it's not equal

Comment: @Kyle Yeah your class doesn't have a definition for length, you'll have to define something yourself that returns the length, then call that.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia what if i just can't control my classes? am i able to change instead of comparing lenghts, comparing topIndex?

Comment: @Kyle oh sorry that length should probably say `size()`

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia kevin, tested the code. When they are equal it gives a main thread error: null pointer exception! and when one of the arrays is null, gives the same exception.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia fixed the errors before but now when testing: It gives a main exception nullpointer error whenever i check if one of them are null or when they are equal.

Comment: @Kyle that seems pretty odd, can you show all the code you are running in your question to produce the NPE?

Comment: This is the worst code segment i have ever seen, so many mistakes in just few lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Your equals implementation is obvioiusly wrong. You are returning true if just one element matches. This means, the only time you will get false is, when all entries mismatch one to one.

What you are looking for is to return false, if any corresponding elements do not match and return true at the end of running loop.

You must also return false, if the size of the two stacks are different.

Comment: Sorry but this should be a comment.

Comment: flipped it, made it equal to false if one of elements not true.

Comment: added base cases too all, now i get a static context error when it checks in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.valueOf() method in java,this method converts different types of values into string.

If s and t are two stack objects

```
String a = String.valueOf(s);
String b= String.valueOf(t);

return a.equals(b); // will return true if stacks are equal
```

This method will also take care if any of the stack is null.